# Elixir Flow works in local machine, but does not process data and throw: [warn] ** Undefined handle_info in "GenStage.Streamer" in AWS Fargate

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have been trying to use Elixir Flow (Lib built from GenStage) to process/stream data from AWS S3 bucket files, and write to AWS RDS DB.

I have been able to do this successfully in my local machine, but when I deployed my app to AWS ECS/Fargate or EC2, it does not work as expected.
Below is my implementation:

```
  def load_file(file_name) do
    window = Flow.Window.count(100)
    file_name
    |> HTTPStream.get()
    |> HTTPStreamUtil.lines()
    |> Flow.from_enumerable()
    |> Flow.filter(&(String.match?(&1, ~r/^rec/)))
    |> Flow.map(fn line ->
      line
      |> String.replace("\n", "")
      |> String.replace("\"", "")
      |> String.split(";")
      |> transform
    end)
    |> Flow.partition(window: window, key: {:key, "day_type_no"})
    |> Flow.reduce(fn -> [] end, fn item, batch -> [item | batch] end)
    |> Flow.on_trigger(fn items ->
      items
      |> add_timestamps
      |> Database.Routes.create_multiple_day_type
      {[items], items}
    end)
    |> Flow.run()
  end
```

When I run my application in AWS Fargate or EC2, I am seeing log below and part/all of the data are not processed.

```
[warn] ** Undefined handle_info in "GenStage.Streamer"
** Unhandled message: {:tcp, #Port<0.20>, "    \"SBST#c29      #01#06#2019#3\"\r\nrec;    20200512;       32510;              \"SBST#37       #01#07#2019#4\"\r\nrec;    20200512;       32511;              \"SBST#31       #03#00#2019#5\"\r\nrec;    20200512;       32512;              \"SBST#298      #01#05#2019#6\"\r\nrec;    20200512;       32513;              \"SBST#c40      #02#06#2019#7\"\r\nrec;    20200512;       32514;              \"SBST#229      #02#06#2019#1\"\r\nrec;    20200512;       32515;              \"SBST#298      #01#00#2019#2\"\r\nrec;    20200512;       32516;              \"SBST#c291     #01#00#2019#3\"\r\nrec;    20200512;       32517;              \"SBST#38       #03#00#2019#4\"\r\nrec;    20200512;       32518;              \"SBST#33       #06#04#2019#5\"\r\nrec;    20200512;       32519;              \"SBST#2N       #01#05#2019#6\"\r\nrec;    20200512;       32520;              \"SBST#401      #02#06#2019#7\"\r\nrec;    20200512;       32521;              \"SBST#c23      #01#00#2019#1\"\r\nrec;    20200512;       32523;              \"SBST#c291     #01#06#2019#3\"\r\nrec;    20200512;       32524;              \"SBST#38       #01#07#2019#4\"\r\nrec;    20200512;       32525;              \"SBST#33       #06#07#2019#5\"\r\nrec;    20200512;       32526;              \"SBST#31       #01#05#2019#6\"\r\nrec;    20200512;       32527;              \"SBST#42       #03#06#2019#7\"\r\nrec;    20200512;       32528;              \"SBST#c23      #01#06#2019#1\"\r\nrec;    20200512;       32529;              \"SBST#2N       #01#65#2019#2\"\r\nrec;    20200512;       32530;              \"SBST#292      #01#00#2019#3\"\r\nrec;    20200512;       32531;              \"SBST#c39      #01#00#2019#4\"\r\nrec;    20200512;       32532;              \"SBST#35       #02#00#2019#5\"\r\nrec;    20200512;       32533;              \"SBST#33       #02#05#2019#6\"\r\nrec;    20200512;       32534;              \"SBST#45       #01#06#2019#7\"\r\nrec;    20200512;       32535;              \"SBST#c29      #01#00#2019#1\"\r\nrec;    20200512;       32536;              \"SBST#31       #03#00#2019#2\"\r\nrec;    20200512;       32537;              \"SBST#292      #01#06#2019#3\"\r\nrec;    20200512;       32538;              \"SBST#c39      #01#07#2019#4\"\r\nrec;    20200512;       32539;              \"SBST#37       #03#00#2019#5\"\r\nrec;    20200512;       32540;              \"SBST#35       #02#05#2019#6\"\r\nrec;    20200512;       32541;              \"SBST#c46      #03#06#2019#7\"\r\nrec;    20200512;       32542;              \"SBST#c29      #01#06#2019#1\"\r\nrec;    20200512;       32543;              \"SBST#33       #06#25#2019#2\"\r\nrec;    20200512;       32544;              \"SBST#c293     #05#00#2019#3\"\r\nrec;    20200512;       32545;              \"SBST#4        #02#00#2019#4\"\r\nrec;    20200512;       32546;              \"SBST#37       #01#07#2019#5\"\r\nrec;    20200512;       32547;              \"SBST#37       #01#05#2019#6\"\r\nrec;    20200512;       32548;              \"SBST#47       #02#06#2019#7\"\r\nrec;    20200512;       32549;              \"SBST#c291     #01#00#2019#1\"\r\nrec;    20200512;       32550;              \"SBST#33       #06#07#2019#2\"\r\nrec;    20200512;       32551;              \"SBST#c293     #01#06#2019#3\"\r\nrec;    20200512;       32552;              \"SBST#c40      #02#00#2019#4\"\r\nrec;    20200512;       32553;              \"SBST#38       #03#00#2019#5\"\r\nrec;    20200512;       32554;              \"SBST#38       #03#05#2019#6\"\r\nrec;    20200512;       32555;              \"SBST#4N       #01#67#2019#7\"\r\nrec;    20200512;       32556;              \"SBST#c291     #01#06#2019#1\"\r\nrec;    20200512;       32557;              \"SBST#35       #02#00#2019#2\"\r\nrec;    20200512;       32558;              \"SBST#298      #01#00#2019#3\"\r\nrec;    20200512;       32559;              \"SBST#c40      #01#07#2019#4\"\r\nrec;    20200512;       32560;              \"SBST#38       #01#07#2019#5\"\r\nrec;    20200512;       32561;              \"SBST#c39      #01#05#2019#6\"\r\nrec;    20200512;       32562;              \"SBST#506      #02#06#2019#7\"\r\nrec;    20200512;       32563;              \"SBST#292      #01#00#2019#1\"\r\nrec;    20200512;       32564;              \"SBST#37       #03#00#2019#2\"\r\nrec;    202" <> ...}
** Stream started at:
    (gen_stage 1.0.0) lib/gen_stage.ex:1609: GenStage.from_enumerable/2
    (stdlib 3.13) supervisor.erl:385: :supervisor.do_start_child_i/3
    (stdlib 3.13) supervisor.erl:371: :supervisor.do_start_child/2
    (stdlib 3.13) supervisor.erl:677: :supervisor.handle_start_child/2
    (stdlib 3.13) supervisor.erl:426: :supervisor.handle_call/3
    (stdlib 3.13) gen_server.erl:706: :gen_server.try_handle_call/4
    (stdlib 3.13) gen_server.erl:735: :gen_server.handle_msg/6
    (stdlib 3.13) proc_lib.erl:226: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
```

I have tried with different Flow.Window e.g. Count, Global etc, none of them work as expected. Also I suspect it can be my remote server/task do not have enable CPU/Memory, I have tried to increase task CPU to 2vCPU, it did help to process more data, but not all data.

The wired thing is that this code works perfectly in my local machine (prolly cos of my pc is powerful??). I would like to check with you guys to see anyone has any idea why this might happen?

Thank you so much.

Comment: that's one long unhandled message

Comment: Yes! That's all the unhandled data, which is not really expected...

Comment: Is this `HTTPStreamUtil.lines()` function works right on AWS ECS/Fargate?

Comment: Hi @z5ottu, I also suspected that function, it worked okay in local machine, but I think it might be HTTPStream returned tuple in AWS Fargate, like (:tcp, :some_tcp_port, :the_actual_data). Anyway, I changed my approach, it worked. The code is in the anws below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried another approach that download the file from S3 to a mounted docker volume then stream the data, it worked. Below are the changes.

```
  def load_file(file_name) do
    # download vdv452 file
    file_path = Application.get_env(:ex_aws, :docker_volume) <> (String.split(file_name, "/") |> List.last)
    ExAws.S3.download_file(Application.get_env(:ex_aws, :s3_bucket_name), file_name, file_path, timeout: 3600)
    |> ExAws.request!

    # stream file data
    file_path
    |> File.stream!
    |> Flow.from_enumerable()
    |> Flow.filter(&(String.match?(&1, ~r/^rec/)))
    |> Flow.map(fn line ->
      line
      |> String.replace("\n", "")
      |> String.replace("\"", "")
      |> String.split(";")
      |> transform
    end)
    |> Flow.partition(window: Flow.Window.count(1_000))
    |> Flow.reduce(fn -> [] end, fn item, batch -> [item | batch] end)
    |> Flow.on_trigger(fn items ->
      items
      |> add_timestamps
      |> Database.Routes.create_multiple_route_sequence
      {[items], items}
    end)
    |> Flow.run()
  end
```